# artifactory: how to delete old backups and set retention to work?

Tags: artifactory

We are not able to delete the old backups even though retention is in place.

Could you please help me how to delete the old backups from artifactory and how to make retention to work which is already in place.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Rammohan

Answer (score 2):

In order for the backup retention in Artifactory to kick in you have to have the following:

1. The retention period must expire. Meaning that if you set 168 hours, it will have to expire first before the retention will be able to work.
2. The last backup MUST finish without any errors. Meaning that even if the 168 hours expired, if the last backup had errors, the retention will not kick in.

Check your logs for backup errors.

Also you can always delete it manually by going to the backup folder and delete the folder that contains the old backup. Please NOTE that the daily, or any other incremental backup will have only one folder and you should not delete it!.

Comment: Thanks Ariel. When i verified i found no space left on the device error which ended the backups with errors so retention failed to execute. Could you please let us know how to remove the old backups manually to free the space on the disk. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, Go to the backup folder and delete the backup that you wish, same as you delete any folder...  :)

Comment: Thanks Ariel.. Just would like to know deleting manually won't impact anything right.

Comment: Indeed. Just make sure to note that you wont have this specific backup....